# Possible to change time of SO new questions digest?

Tags: feature-request, email, filtering, newest-questions, tag-filters

I get the *New questions digest message* every day at **~07:56**.
This means that by the time I get to view/answer them, the digest message waited in my email inbox for several long hours.

Below is the settings page, and I don't see a possibility to set the time the daily message is prepared.

### Is it possible to config the *time* when New questions are collected and sent?

[image: New questions setup]

Comment: As this mechanism is probably only on SO, you should've asked it on meta.SO. I guess.

Comment: @MARamezani: Then why does the dialog list "on **All Sites** and display the Stack Exchange (not Stack Overflow) logo?

Comment: The issue with this is internationalisation. For someone it is going to be at an awkward time. You being in UTC +2 suggests it is sent out at 6UTC - so people can read it when they wake up.

Comment: @Tim. Letting an SOer set the time - when New questions are collected and sent - to the time the SOer is waking up (as opposed to the time when people in the _EST_ timezone are waking up) will let people not in North America fill welcome on SO ;-)

Comment: @boardrider I highly doubt they will add any "configurable options", they are fairly against those types of things...